# How to set AutoGrowNestedPaths=false globally?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to find a way to set AutoGrowNestedPaths=false globally.

I'm currently using a Java based configuration approach with a WebConfig extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

Although Biju answer was pointing me in the right direction, the example code can be much cleaner and avoiding to reconfigure everything. This is the code I'm using now:

```
@Bean
public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
    RequestMappingHandlerAdapter bean = super.requestMappingHandlerAdapter();
    ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer webBindingInitializer = (ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer) bean.getWebBindingInitializer();
    webBindingInitializer.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(false);
    return bean;
}
```

Note that is a pitty Spring's WebMvcConfigurationSupport cannot directly configure the WebBindingInitializer. See also https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8984

Comment: SPR-8984 is fixed in 3.2

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by directly extending your web configuration from [WebMvcConfigurationSupport](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html) :

```
 @Configuration
 public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
        ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer webBindingInitializer = new ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer();
        webBindingInitializer.setConversionService(mvcConversionService());
        webBindingInitializer.setValidator(mvcValidator());
        webBindingInitializer.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(false);


        List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers = new ArrayList<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver>();
        addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);

        List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> returnValueHandlers = new ArrayList<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler>();
        addReturnValueHandlers(returnValueHandlers);

        RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter = new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
        adapter.setMessageConverters(getMessageConverters());
        adapter.setWebBindingInitializer(webBindingInitializer);
        adapter.setCustomArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
        adapter.setCustomReturnValueHandlers(returnValueHandlers);
        return adapter;
    }
 }
```